# How to add values to specific column in 2D arrays?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I suppose to fill the value each time the user try to make an appointment. There is Two type of Appointment: Appointment a and Appointment b. Each appointment can make it only 4 a day. So, my dimensional would have two columns for types of appointment and 4 rows for 4 appointments. I just tried if the user types only "a".
If the user types "a" for the first time, my 2D array will look like:

```
1111
1000
```

If the user types "a" for the second time, the 2D array will look like:

```
1111
1200
```

And so on... So finally the 2D array will look like:

```
1111
1234
```

---

```
  int[,] slots = new int[4,2];
  string appt_type;
  string choice = "Y";
  while (choice == "Y")
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a or b");
    appt_type = Console.ReadLine();
    if (appt_type == "a")
    {
      for (int i=0; i<slots.GetLength(0); i++) 
      {
        for (int j=0; j<slots.GetLength(1); j++) 
        {
          slots[i,0] = 1;
          slots[i,j] = i+1;
        }
      }

      int q = 0;
      foreach (int i in slots)
      {
        if ((q%2) == 1)
          Console.WriteLine(i + " ");
        else
          Console.Write(i + " ");
        q++;
      }
  }

}
```

My final output is what I expect it. However, I want to fill each of the second column each time the user enters "a".

First enters "a"

1111 1000

Second time enters "a"

```
1111 1200
```

Third time enters "a"

```
1111 1230
```

Fourth time enters "a"

```
1111 1234
```

Comment: It looks like you have a code that goes through each element of your 2d array. Do you know how it works?

Answer (score 0):

First of all,your for loop isn't as you want it,because before the user inputs "a" or "b" you already initialized in the for loop inside for loop,the array as it should be in the end.After the for loops the array is 1111 1234.

You can create a counter variable to count the number of times the user had entered "a" each time that you get the input.In this specific case there is a connection between the row of the array,and the amount of "a"'s the user has entered so I initialized the counter with 0 even though it value goes up only if you enter "a" again.The amount of "a"'s the user has entered-1 because it is 1 for sure after it gets into the forloop,so thats why you can also set it as the element of the array that you wanted to change.

Additionally,you can use while(true) instead of creating a variable and leave it the same.
Its pretty much like this:(Tried to use your way printing it)

```
  int[,] slots = new int[4, 2];
        string appt_type;
        int counter = 0;//counts how many times the user had enter the letter "a"
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a or b");
            appt_type = Console.ReadLine();
            if (appt_type == "a")
            {
                counter++;
                for (int i = 0; i < slots.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < slots.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        slots[i, 0] = 1;
                        slots[counter - 1,1 ] = counter;//note:all of the elements that you want to change are in column 1 of the array
                    }
                }
                int q = 1;//the position of i in the array
                foreach (int i in slots)
                {
                    if(q%2!=1)
                        Console.WriteLine(i+" " );
                    else
                        Console.Write(i);
                    q++;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for your code to allow the user to input his/her choice and make the code do something based on that choice, you need to check the element's value if it is 0 or something else and then do something based on that value. Here is a quick untested fix, but you can get the gist:

```
for (int i=0; i<slots.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<slots.GetLength(1); j++) 
    {
        if (slots[i,j] == 0)
        {
            slots[i,j] = i+1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I think your code can still be improved in a lot more ways. Here are my suggestions:

- Break apart your code in methods to make it easier to read.
  Separate the routines when *A* is selected, when *B* is selected, and
  when slots is displayed.
- It is clear that upon selecting choice *A*, the first column of the
  array is set to 1111 and does not change up to the end, so set it
  once and forget about going through it by checking if the first
  element of the column is equal to 1.
- You don't have to go through all of the elements in the second column
  just to set the value. Just check for the first 0 that you encounter 
  and set it to the current index + 1.
- Use `break` to get out of loops easily and eliminate the curly braces to
  make the code look a bit cleaner.
- Ignore the case when comparing strings, because `a != A`.

Here is a suggested and tested refactor. Add a break point on `while(true)`, make it run in debug mode, and see how the code flows on every user input:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var slots = new int[4, 2];
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Do you want to proceed? [Y/N]");
            var choice = Console.ReadLine();

            if (!choice.Equals("y", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))   
                break;

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a or b: ");
            var appt_type = Console.ReadLine();

            if (appt_type.Equals("a", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                slots = AssignScheduleA(slots);

            else if (appt_type.Equals("b", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                AssignScheduleB(slots);

            DisplaySlotsValue(slots);
        }
    }

    private static int[,] AssignScheduleA(int[,] slots)
    {
        if (slots[0,0] != 1)
        {
            for(int idx1 = 0; idx1 < slots.GetLength(0); idx1++)
                slots[idx1, 0] = 1;
        }    

        for(int idx2 = 0; idx2 < slots.GetLength(0); idx2++)
        {
            if (slots[idx2, 1] == 0)
            {
                slots[idx2, 1] = idx2 + 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        return slots;
    }

    private static void AssignScheduleB(int[,] slots)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();    
    }

    private static void DisplaySlotsValue(int[,] slots)
    {
        for (int idx1 = 0; idx1 < slots.GetLength(0); idx1++)
            Console.Write(slots[idx1, 0]);

        Console.WriteLine();

        for (int idx2 = 0; idx2 < slots.GetLength(0); idx2++)
            Console.Write(slots[idx2, 1]);

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

If you go over this while on debug mode, you will understand how the code will let the user make a choice every time and fill in the array based on the choice. This code can still be improved and that can be something that you do as you learn more about C#. Happy coding!